# List of Spark SQL supported data stores

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, hbase, apache-spark-sql, spring-jdbc

I am very beginner here. Sorry If I asked duplicate/silly question.

Coming to point, as my product(Java web application) demands, I need to write some application which should push data to any of data stores(based on some configuration). The data store can be RDBMS, Hive or any NoSQL data store. So the query is, is SparkSql is best fit for my case, if yes, can I have list of data stores supported by Spark SQL. If Spark won't do this, are they any other approaches.

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Yes! SparkSql(Spark) is the best fit for your usecase.
As per my knowledge, SparkSql supports RDBMS, Hive, and any NoSQL data store.

SparkSQL may not have APIs to directly access few stores but with a little help from Spark's API, you should be able to connect any data store.

We have been using Spark to connect to RDBMS, Cassandra, HBase, ElasticSearch, Solr, Hive, S3, HDFS etc.